# Retrieve login name into column

Tags: oracle, authentication, triggers, oracle-apex

I have created a trigger.
In this trigger I would like to have the login user name returned, among other things.

```
     create or replace trigger trg_form_submitted
       after insert or delete or update on tbl1
       for each ROW
     declare
       v_user varchar2(30);
       v_date varchar2(30);
     begin
       select v('&APP_USER'),  to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) into v_user,v_date from dual;
      
       if INSERTING THEN
          ....
```

However this unfortunately does not work I do not get the login name.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Littlefoot s' answer is 100% correct, there is a more performant option available now. The `V` is a function that has to be executed every time. A faster way to get the same data outside of your apex application is to use `SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER')` which is instant.
Also Note that you don't have to do `SELECT INTO` to assign variables. Your trigger will be a bit more efficient (one less call to the sql engine) if you just assign the variables:

```
    create or replace trigger trg_form_submitted
       after insert or delete or update on tbl1
       for each ROW
     declare
       v_user varchar2(30);
       v_date varchar2(30);
     begin
       v_user := SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER');
       v_date := to_char(sysdate, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' );
      
       if INSERTING THEN
          ....
```

A couple more tips

- A good naming convention is to start the trigger name with the table name and add a suffix, like tbl1_aiud (aiud stands for "after insert update delete"). That way the object name indicates it is related to "tbl1". Naming it "trg" is like naming your work document "Word document xyz.doc"...
- Storing a date in a variable or column of datatype `VARCHAR2` is a bad idea in 99% of the cases. The datatype DATE is extremely powerful - use that if the data is a date.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have included your suggestions. If I might ask you one more thing, you said that using datatype varchar2 for a date is bad practice. How can I use the datatype date with the same functionality, so that I get the date in this format?

Comment: Not a problem. I suggest you read up on the dates concept in oracle. A date is just a date, it does not have a format in the database. The format is how you represent that date in a query, using a format mask of your choice. There is plenty of documentation on that, I can't even start beginning to explain - many much smarter than me have already done that. Google is your friend: the oracle documentation is great and there are a ton of blogs on this.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you misused it.

Correct syntax is

```
v ('APP_USER')
```

(remove the ampersand `&` sign).